# Using AngularJS to style label when ng-model changes in a text field

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

A few days back, I asked the following question:

*I've searched for how to do this, and I've not had any luck.  I'm fairly inexperienced with web            stuff, so perhaps it's so trivial that no one needs to ask how to do it :(
Suppose I have an HTML text input field with a label, like this:*

```
<label for = "stuff">Stuff</label>
<input type = "text" name = "stuffz" id="stuff" value = "hello!">
```

*Now suppose the text input field value is changed.  Is there a way to use AngularJS to restyle the label (Like, turn it green, for example) when this change occurs?  I've looked into using ng-change and ng-class, but I'm not knowledgeable enough about how these work to use them in this manner.*

When I tested the solution provided, which was:

CSS

```
.marvellous {
 color: green;
 }
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="demo">

<label for="stuff" ng-class="{ 'marvellous' : !!hasChanged }">Stuff</label>
<input type="text" id="stuff" ng-model="myModel" ng-change="hasChanged = true"></div>
```

It worked, but only when I manually changed the text field (i.e. I typed stuff in the text field directly).  However, in the particular application I'm working on, I need for the labels to be restyled when the value stored in ng-model changes.  Unfortunately, I falsely assumed that if this method worked when I manually changed the text field, it must work if ng-model were to change as well.  I've come to find out that it doesn't.

What's the reason for this? And how can I make the label re-style when ng-model changes?

Thanks!

EDIT: When I say "ng-model changes," what I mean is..in my controller, there is a variable that is used to populate the text fields of the app that I'm working on.  However, when the user clicks an "import changes" button, this variable is changed according to the changes that they are importing, which consequently changes the corresponding text fields linked to that variable.  Ultimately, I want all of the labels attached to these changed text fields to be highlighted for the user to see.  I'm sorry for my vagueness.

Comment: `I need for the labels to be restyled when the value stored in ng-model changes` You would need to change the flag when you programatically change ngModel value.. `ng-change` is for user input on the element alone. Or just have a function bound to ng-class which will determine if the value was changed or not and send the corrent flag. http://plnkr.co/edit/2eNL0M?p=preview

Comment: Is this in a form or just random inputs on the page?

Comment: Or if uare using for you could assign class to formfield's dirty flag Instead of managing a flag urself.

Answer (score 1):

Each input in an angular js form has meta data properties to help you. For example

```
<form id="form">
   <label for="stuff" ng-class="{ 'marvellous' : form.stuff.$dirty}">Stuff</label>
   <input type="text" id="stuff" ng-model="myModel" ng-change="hasChanged = true">
</form>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using `$scope.$watch` :

```js
function demoCtrl ($scope) {
  
  $scope.$watch('myModel', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue) {
      $scope.hasChanged = true;
    }
  });
  
  $scope.changeMyModel = function () {
    $scope.myModel = 'wonderful';
  };
  
}
```

```css
.marvellous {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="demoCtrl">
  
  <label for="stuff" ng-class="{ 'marvellous' : !!hasChanged }">Stuff</label>
  <input type="text" id="stuff" ng-model="myModel" ng-change="hasChanged = true">
  
  <button ng-click="changeMyModel()">change model</button>

</div>
```

Comment: However, my next question is..is there a way to apply this in a way that allows me to watch each attribute of a JSON object for changes and run the function for that attribute only when it does?  For example..lets say my object has a firstname, lastname, and middlename.  Now lets say firstname and middlename are changed when the button is pushed.  How would I use this approach to indicate that these fields change so that I can restyle them and not all of the fields connected to the object?

Comment: Yep. You need to activate the `deep watch mode` on your `$watch` method. Assume you got `$scope.profile = { firstName: 'a', lastName: 'b' };`, you can do `$scope.$watch('profile', function () { ... }, true);`

Comment: Just one other question...in your original example, you give the function the parameters 'newValue' and 'oldValue'.  I guess I'm still struggling to wrap my head around this whole concept, but..if that function is automatically called when a change is made to a field, how are arguments ever sent to that function?  Or does newValue automatically detect the new value and oldValue automatically detect the previous value?  Thanks.

Comment: Both `newValue` and `oldValue` will be objects, but `oldValue` will be a deep copy of your object before it changes

Comment: Does $scope.$watch run every time the page refreshes?  My implementation still isn't working, and when I put at break at $scope.$watch in the file in chrome dev tools, the line only runs at a page refresh but not when I click my import button.

Comment: Can you tell if you are doing some form validation work ? Cause there is a *much simpler* way to do that, without watching objects & all. I think you're going to a wrong way. Tell moar, if you want we could go to the chat

Comment: And nope, `$scope.$watch` call its callback on each listened changes **AND** on view load, at first render.

Comment: At this point in my project, I'm not trying to do any form validation.  Unless I'm misunderstanding what you mean by form validation, all I'm attempting to do is to track the changes made to a form after an XML file containing changes to various fields has been imported via highlighting each field that was changed.  Perhaps there is an easier way to do this than how I'm approaching it?  


Like I said, I've had to learn much of this angular and web stuff on the fly, so my understanding of it is superficial at best.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <!--Use ng-style !!!  replace your lable with this--->
   <label for="stuff" ng-style="hasChanged()">Stuff</label> 


   and define your function like this below---

    $scope.hasChanged = function(){
      if($scope.myModel !== initValue){
            return { color: "green" }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this method would work tracking and adjusting individual fields.  If I call hasChanged() for the ng-style directive for every field in the form, then any change in the form will cause all of the fields to change color, right?  Is there a way I could use this method for only styling individual fields when its corresponding attribute changes?

Comment: ya that's correct Bob. But if you have limited fields in form you can try this solution for  styling individual fields when its corresponding attribute changes .chk out this http://plnkr.co/edit/9sBmM3WImqC8vHoescvR